# How to run a Python Module directly in Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: python, pip

I want to make and launch a command interpreter in Python for Linux. I've used Python's cmd class to run the program.

Currently, I run the program by executing
`python main.py` (where main.py is the main project file).

I want to be able to run my project by just typing in my project name into the terminal **and** publish this project on PIP. How do I do that?

**EDIT**

Im aware that there are multiple examples on the web which demonstrate how to execute a python file directly by filename (adding Python shebang at start of file).

It does answer first half of my question, but I also intend to publish this package on PIP. All tutorials I read on publishing packages on PIP direct me to make python modules which can be run in other python programs, something I dont want. I want to make a python package which can be run directly on

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? This helps with the first part of your question:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/244378/running-python-file-in-terminal

Comment: When it comes to publishing your project into PIP, I think you're looking for PyPi. Here is a tutorial that I found that may be helpful:

https://medium.com/@joel.barmettler/how-to-upload-your-python-package-to-pypi-65edc5fe9c56

Comment: @burntchowmein I updated the question in response to your first comment, apologies for that.

Comment: [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#scripts) is how you include scripts in a python package packaged with `setuptools`

Answer (score 2):

If you package your package with `setuptools` (which is the most modern way as far as I know), you can just add `entry_points` to your `setup`.

Example: You want a script calling the function `bar()` in the module `foo` and the script should be called via the terminal with the command `bar`, then your `setup` will look like:

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        "console_scripts": [
            "bar = foo:bar",
        ],
    },
    ...
)
```

This is more or less well documented [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#scripts).